# Is it possible to serve Ad Manager (DFP) ads in newsletters and track impressions and clicks

Tags: ads, newsletter, google-dfp

I'm trying to serve ads from Google Ad Manager (DFP) campaigns using html.

[Google says it can be done](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1258792) and offers sample syntax. Based on this I have succeeded in displaying test ads in newsletters (or Hotmail) that come from DFP and click through to the right place.

What I cannot do is record impressions and clicks in Ad Manager - so I'm not yet achieving anything.

Please note: I know how to code newsletter links and see click throughs in Google Analytics. This is a good way of knowing traffic to your own site, but I want to know traffic to other sites. I think that Ad Manager support for newsletters would be of great value to many people.

I've tried to get this a number of times, including with the help of a professional programmer. I've tried getting urls for the ads I want to display both from the ad manager admin and by putting a test ad on a page using Ad Manager tags. The urls I get are quite different from the [example offered by Google (page bottom)](http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1258792), so I can't figure out what variables to pass and how.

I'm hoping that someone is already doing this, or that Google reads this and supports the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But you can only use .GIF's and JPEG's as your creatives with 1x1 pixel tracker.
Also the DFP Macro %i (For impressions) and %c (for clicks) can be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Use simplified URL tags for mobile
https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2623168?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Even though the link might provide the answer, you should include the code in your answer. The link might become invalid and so would your answer.